# How to pass Hibernate Entity to Android Application

Tags: java, android, spring, hibernate

I have a server running in Java and all the data inserted on it is stored in a MySQL database, using Hibernate.

I'm trying to pass all this data to my Android application, so I have to have the same Entities classes declared on both sides. The point is Android does not support Hibernate, so I can't have the Hibernate annotations in my Android entity classes.

How could I solve this problem?

I have thought in creating an auxiliary class which would be called EntityAndroid and it will not have the Hibernate Annotations. So whenever an Android request come to the server, I would convert an Entity class (with Hibernate stuffs) to EntityAndroid class (similar to the other one, but without Hibernate stuffs), and pass this auxiliary object to Android app (Obviously, I would have the same EntityAndroid class of server in Android app). This would demand too much of the server since I have so many relations between tables.

Comment: Thanks for the links.. but here I don't have the intention of implementing Hibernate in Android. I just would like to know better ways of sending entity created with hibernate to android

Comment: How are you sending the entity? JSON, XML? Just have a class with the same fields.

Comment: I'm sending with JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating new entity classes both in Android and Server project and I'm using these classes to pass from Server to Android.
These classes don't have the annotations from Hibernate and all the foreign keys are treated as Integer (In Hibernate I have the whole object entity of the foreign key). So before sending these entities to the app, I make this conversion, which is simply an iteration through all fields of an hibernate entity filling the android entity (identical of hibernate entity but without annotations and foreign keys being integers)

This may not be the best solution cause it can waste too much of the processor and memory but as I will not have so many entities to be converted I guess that should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use hibernate XML mapping style?
You will be using classes without annotations and this may clear the error in Android.

Comment: I haven't thought this before. I will be looking for it, but wouldn't I have to implement or extend any Hibernate classes while creating an Entity? If so, this wouldn't work cause i would not have the same classes on both sides

Comment: No, you dont have to extend from anything (everything is mapped at the XML file), all POJOs will be clean and maybe this will help you to eliminate the errors. PD. I have never used annotations on my projects but i have read about it. I always use XML style.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to me to have Entities on Android if you store / retrieve the data via your server. I would focus on creating webservices on the server side for retrieving and storing your changes.

Let your webservice serialize the entity objects to a JSON data structure (for example) that you can read and convert back to an object in your Android app. When an object was changed in your client you can send it back to the server via a webservice which converts the JSON structure back to an entity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I'm doing, besides the fact of changing the object in the client. this will not happen, all the data is changed in the server and I just read these data and send them to android app.. I'm already using json to send the objects.. the only thing is I don't have exactly the same class on both sides because hibernate is not supported on android

Comment: Yes but you can map the JSON data to a different object. Or perhaps build a shared java interface library which only contains the interfaces for your entity objects. Let your entity classes implement this on the server side and let your Android client implement them on the client side.